# Mp4 corrupting when I crop it using MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to take an input file and convert it to a 9:16 aspect ration using python.

For some reason the video works when I try to play it in VS Code but doesn't work when I try to use Windows Media Player(it says the video is corrupted).

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip, TextClip, CompositeVideoClip, concatenate_audioclips

def closest_resolution(height):
    width = (9/16) * height
    rounded_width = round(width)
    adjusted_height = round((16/9) * rounded_width)

    return rounded_width, adjusted_height

input_video = "Output Videos/output2.mp4"
video = VideoFileClip(input_video)
width, height = closest_resolution(1080)

video = video.crop(x1=video.size[0] / 2 - width / 2, y1=0, width=width, height=height)
print(video.size)
video.write_videofile("output.mp4", codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

I tried changing the format and messing with it. The confusing thing for me is that the video works in VS Code.